# Any way to keep each request separate in the Rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to have the logs from each request be grouped together and easy to tell apart from another request's logs, eg

```
**********************

Started GET "/" for 67.205.67.76 at 2013-09-15 00:05:15 -0700
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Rendered root/_index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_fonts_hack.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_ie_version_vars.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered topbars/_logged_out_topbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_old_browser_warnings.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

**********************

Started GET "/" for 67.205.67.76 at 2013-09-15 00:05:15 -0700
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Rendered root/_index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_fonts_hack.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_ie_version_vars.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered topbars/_logged_out_topbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_old_browser_warnings.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

***********************
```

Is something like this possible? sometimes in my logs currently its kind of hard to visually see where one request begins and another ends, and sometimes logs from different requests get interspersed.

Comment: you could put in a global before filter that just logs some stars to the logger...

Comment: What will happen when you get two concurrent requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option would be to use the [request uuid](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/keeping-your-logs-from-becoming-an-unreadable-mess/)

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid]
```

Comment: What about logs from things like Rake tasks though...

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt seem like it from what I can tell, but next best thing: add Pid and Thread object_id tags to each log, then search for and highlight a particular tag once you get to the start of a request, and then all the highlighted lines will be the ones in your request.

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda {|r| "#{Process.pid}##{Thread.current.object_id}" } ]
```