# rails multiple requests are mixed inside logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I was confronted with issue where I need to parse my logs for some SQL queries, but I do multiple requests per page and it's hard to read them because they are all mixed together
[image]

Is there any way I can order them? Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Rails simply logs them in their chronological order , how would you like to order them ?

Comment: @Joel_Blum I would like to view each action separately, so I know what's going on in each request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926352/any-way-to-keep-each-request-separate-in-the-rails-log

Comment: @Joel_Blum that's not something that I'm looking for, they just suggest adding a tag to each log and then search for a highlighted tag
I have lots of requests going concurrently, so it's kinda messy

Comment: I don't see this functionality provided in Rails, maybe someone built some gem for it but I couldn't find anything. Good luck!